Transferred github repository from one account to another but contributions made with old account don't show up
I followed the docs https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository and I successfully transferred ownership of the repos and also transferred the old account's mail to the new account's mail
but I'm not able to find any contributions in my new account into these repos so to debug this I took a commit in my transferred repo to inspect it and found this mail ID in its config SYSHIL@users.noreply.github.com I think this is some sort of default mail for privacy? how do I get around this and get all those commits in my new account?
Thanks in advance !

I think This and this might help you solve the issue.
The link you provided which you have followed states:

Git information about commits, including contributions, is preserved.

So there's a chance you might have made a mistake in some steps.
And also there's this too:

When you transfer a repository from an organization to a personal account, the repository's read-only collaborators will not be transferred. This is because collaborators can't have read-only access to repositories owned by a personal account.

I suggest reading the article again and check everything you have done to see what has happened. I hope this helps.
